# Fitting 1 speed tyres on 21 speed bike

Tags: tire, hybrid-bike

My bike (A FireFox Sniper V) has 26x2.1 knobbies. I cycle on urban roads, so I decided to upgrade to 26x1.95 hybrid tyres from BTWIN. But they have mentioned that it is a 1 speed hybrid tyre. Will it work on my 21 (3 front, 7 rear) speed bike?

From India

Comment: Curious, do you have a link to the 'one speed' tires?

Comment: Here is a link to a "1 Speed Hybrid Bike Tyre" by BTWIN https://www.decathlon.in/p/8344715/bike-inner-tubes-and-tires/1-speed-hybrid-bike-26x195-trekking-tyre In the description it says "The Speed 1 trekking tyre " so maybe Speed 1 is a model.

Comment: Reading the text, "Speed 1" is the model,  1 Speed in the title - maybe the marketing guys think it will impress the hipsters.

Comment: Oddly, this almost identical question was posted a day after yours.    https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/68831/doubts-about-tire-compatibility-on-my-wheels

Answer (score 8):

The only actual issue if the tyres will fit; and they will from the two 26" sizes you've quoted. Number of gears (speeds) is irrelevant.

Marketing people like to throw in spurious detail often to give the impression they know what they're talking about.

Answer (score 7):

I've never heard of a "1 speed tyre", but it is possible this is a harder durometer rubber to resist wear if the rider does a skid-stop, at the cost of being less grippy.  It should still fit your rim the same.

The only likely gotcha here is whether both 26" tyres are the same size.

Check the ETRTO code on the sidewall.  It will be in the format 559-56 or 56-559.  The bigger number has to be identical, but the other number is the width and your new tyre will be around 46.  Both are in millimetres.

You probably don't need new tubes for this relatively small change in tyre width.

Comment: I agree that this speculative reason is likely. Though, oh my, that would be a good contender for the highly contested _most obnoxious terminology_ award – there is after all no inherent reason why a single speed bike should come without proper brakes, or freehub for that matter!