# Doubts about Tire compatibility on my wheels?

Tags: tire, rims, compatibility, wheels

I want to get a pair of 26 x 2.1  tires for my Bicycle.
My wheels are compatible with these dimensions.
A reputable store near me offers 26x1.95 tires. I am pretty sure that 1.95s are compatible with my 2.1 wheel.
The issue is, these are marketed at tires for a single speed bicycle of theirs. Mine is a 21 (3 x 7) speed bike.

From what I can tell, the wheel matters in matters of compatibility with the gearing, and not the tires as long as it is compatible with my wheel. But still, to be extra sure, does it matter that these tires are marketed for single-speed cycles as long as they are compatible with my wheels ?

Comment: Have you asked this question twice ?  There are an astonishing number of similarities, including the gear setup, the tyre widths, and your location.  Are you looking at a brand of tyre named "1 Speed" or "Speed 1" like the other question ?

Comment: No, it isnt a duplicate, i havent asked again. This was a question my freind was grappling with and he asked me. It appears he asked BSE too. Its just the both of us not knowing the other has asked BSE about the same exact thing.

Comment: @AnAnt sorry I am not accusing - "duplicate" is just stackexchange jargon for seeing the same basic question again.  We try to limit the duplicates, and it helps to point new instances of the question at the older question, where there are often more and better answers.  Good luck with your bike!   I'm closing this as a duplicate, don't take it personally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The amount of gears has no bearing on the type of tyre.

The 26" part refers to the wheel diameter, so this is the most important part.

The 2.1" or 1.95", refer to the width of the tyre. The width of the rim determine which width tyres you should have. If your wheel is ok wth a 2.1 wide tyre, then a 1.95" wide tyre will be absolutely fine.

What you should consider when changing a tyre is the terrain, the puncture protection level, the weight, the durability vs grip and the price. The bike gears alone shouldn't influence the tyre choice.

Comment: It needs to be noted that, while most 26" wheels with decimal-sized widths (eg, 1.75") are compatible, those with fractional widths (eg, 1-7/8") are not.  https://www.sheldonbrown.com/tire-sizing.html